# How can I tell if a third-party repository is reputable?

Tags: centos, repository

Among other things, I want to install ffmpeg on a CentOS server of mine (just a personal server - nothing too special).

I noticed that one set of installation instructions advise to add a DAG repository:

```
[dag]
name=Dag RPM Repository for Red Hat Enterprise Linux
baseurl=http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el$releasever/en/$basearch/dag
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
```

The name sounds familiar but I'm not sure if I've used this one before.  How can I tell if it's reputable / safe / reliable?

Answer (score 0):

Any of the Repositories that Dag works with are reputable. You can check out the [FAQ for starters](http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/FAQ.php).

> A1. What is the Dag RPM Repository ?
>
> It grew out of my personal collection of RPMs, after discovering apt for RPM and the FreshRPMS repository of Matthias Saou, I ended up opening up my own packages and packaging a whole lot more. Since 2005 we've merged our repositories, provided packages for several Red Hat based distributions and a handful of architectures.

The [RPMForge.net](http://repoforge.org/) project replaces some of the packages that were previously provided by the Dag repo.

Lastly you probably are going to want to keep a bookmark to this [CentOS wiki page about the various Repositories](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories). I've been using Redhat based distros for 20ish years and still need to reference this page to keep them all straight.